# VB/C# String.Asc() equivalent method in javascript

Tags: javascript, ascii

I would like to convert char to asc in javascript.

At c#,

```
int asc = Strings.Asc("”");
```

result is 148

At Javascript,

```
var asc = "”".charCodeAt(0);
```

result is 8221

May I know why the result in javascript is 8221 and May I know equivalent method in Javascript?

Full Code :

At c#

```
(Strings.Chr((Strings.Asc("”") - 99))).ToString()
```

This is return 1

I tried at Javascript

```
String.fromCharCode("”".charCodeAt(0)-99)
```

But this does not return the same result.

I would like to convert this code with the same logic in Javascript.

Comment: I've a counter question - where is `148` coming from?

Comment: 148 come from  `Strings.Asc("”")`

Comment: But which *character table*? It's not in ASCII, I checked.

Comment: @VLAZ, Thanks for pointing me out and I also don't see at ASCII table. My target is to convert c# code to js code. Please check my update.

Comment: I've question too: Have read the docs on  [.charCode()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charcodeat.asp)? It outputs unicode of the character. The main difference between the ASCII & UniCode is in the way they encode the character and the number of bits that they use for each. ASCII originally used seven bits to encode each character. ... In contrast, Unicode uses a variable bit encoding program where you can choose between 32, 16, and 8-bit encodings.